# Connection between multiplication table $n * k$ and partial sums of the partial sums of the Dirichlet inverse of the Euler totient function.

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, symmetric-matrices, arithmetic-functions

I am watching this video: [L-functions and the Langlands program (RH Saga S1E2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bzSFNCiKrk&t=13s)

This reminds me of a recurrence:

Let $c=1$ and a recurrence be:

```
t[n, k] = 
 If[And[n > 1, k > 1], 
  If[n > k, t[n, k - 1] - t[n - k, k - 1] + t[n - k + c, k], 
   t[k, n - 1] - t[k - n, n - 1] + t[k - n + c, n]], 0]
```

Then the diagonal sums are tetrahedral numbers:

```
 {1, 4, 10, 20, 35, 56, 84, 120, 165, 220, 286, 364}
 {3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78}
 {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
```

https://oeis.org/A000292

Let $c=0$ and apply the same recurrence:

```
t[n, k] = 
 If[And[n > 1, k > 1], 
  If[n > k, t[n, k - 1] - t[n - k, k - 1] + t[n - k + c, k], 
   t[k, n - 1] - t[k - n, n - 1] + t[k - n + c, n]], 0]
```

Then the diagonal sums are the partial sums of the partial sums of the Dirichlet inverse of the Euler totient function:

```
{1, 4, 8, 16, 22, 34, 47, 62, 73, 94, 113, 144}
{3, 4, 8, 6, 12, 13, 15, 11, 21, 19, 31}
{1, 4, -2, 6, 1, 2, -4, 10, -2, 12} *this*
```

https://oeis.org/A023900

```
 1, -1, -2, {-1, -4, 2, -6, -1, -2, 4, -10, 2, -12} *this*
```

---

```
"c=1 Mathematica program start" 
Clear[nn, t, n, k, c];
nn = 60;
c = 1;
t[n_, 1] = If[n >= 1, n, 0];
t[1, k_] = If[k >= 1, k, 0];
t[n_, k_] := 
  t[n, k] = 
   If[And[n > 1, k > 1], 
    If[n > k, t[n, k - 1] - t[n - k, k - 1] + t[n - k + c, k], 
     t[k, n - 1] - t[k - n, n - 1] + t[k - n + c, n]], 0];
TableForm[Table[Table[t[n, k], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]];
Table[Sum[t[n - k + 1, k], {k, 1, 12}], {n, 1, 12}]
Differences[%]
Differences[%]
"end"
```

---

```
Output:
{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
```

---

```
"c=0 program start" 
Clear[nn, t, n, k, c];
nn = 60;
c = 0;
t[n_, 1] = If[n >= 1, n, 0];
t[1, k_] = If[k >= 1, k, 0];
t[n_, k_] := 
  t[n, k] = 
   If[And[n > 1, k > 1], 
    If[n > k, t[n, k - 1] - t[n - k, k - 1] + t[n - k + c, k], 
     t[k, n - 1] - t[k - n, n - 1] + t[k - n + c, n]], 0];
TableForm[Table[Table[t[n, k], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]];
Table[Sum[t[n - k + 1, k], {k, 1, 12}], {n, 1, 12}]
Differences[%]
Differences[%]
"end"
```

---

```
Output
{-1, -4, 2, -6, -1, -2, 4, -10, 2, -12}
```

Screen dump 1, multiplication table $n*k$:

[image: multiplication table diagonal sums]

Screen dump 2:

[image: other table diagonal sums]

https://oeis.org/A030187
Expansion of eta(q) * eta(q^2) * eta(q^7) * eta(q^14) in powers of q.

**Question:**

> Can you prove that the recurrence for the case $c=1$:
>
> ```
> t[n, k] = 
>  If[And[n > 1, k > 1], 
>   If[n > k, t[n, k - 1] - t[n - k, k - 1] + t[n - k + c, k], 
>    t[k, n - 1] - t[k - n, n - 1] + t[k - n + c, n]], 0]
> ```
>
> gives the multiplication table $n \text{ times } k$?

Comment: Screen dump $1$: the numbers circled in red have the following properties: the product of numbers on the diagonal perpendicular to the main diagonal (that of squares) are just $n!^2$. For example $3*4*3=36=6^2=3!^2$. The addition of numbers on the same diagonal gives the partial sum of squares odd or even depending on the first number of a given diagonal. For example $3+4+3=10=1^2 +3^2$. Since 3, the first number, is odd the addition gives the sum of odd squares up to $3$. (cont)

Comment: Cont: See: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42510/what-are-the-benefits-of-cutting-by-half-the-number-of-multiplications-needed-to/42645#42645 and this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661102/is-there-a-hidden-relation-between-the-sum-of-squares-and-the-factorial#4664888